# How to optimize Latin Modern font with XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, typography, latin-modern

I need to create a XeLaTeX document with many fonts.
I will use many fonts because my documents talk about fonts.

But I want to use Latin Modern as main font.
So I downloaded and installed ALL the open type font on my win7 via http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/latin-modern

First I just did a simple :

```
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}
```

It worked, but for instance I discovered that I couldn't get the small caps. Then I tried a:

```
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX,SmallCapsFont={* Caps}]{Latin Modern Roman}
```

It is working fine but my question is what is the best way to call the LM font in the preamble in order to be sure to get the best typography?

Comment: `fontspec` uses Latin Modern by default, you don’t need any action to use it.

Comment: @KhaledHosny AH ok indeed it was simple like that witouth any "setmainfont" "setmonofont" it seems to work perfectely. Thank you.

Comment: @KhaledHosny the solution you gave me is perfect. May you put it as answer. Then I can validate the post. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

`fontspec` uses Latin Modern by default, you don’t need any action to use it.

Comment: @KhaledHosny Any chance you could humor me and demonstrate how you *would* do it if you wanted to? A platform-independent way of defining a default latex font, something like: `\newfontfamily\latinmodern{lmroman10-regular}`

Comment: What if you changed the main font and want to change back to Latin Modern?

Comment: It does not really work by default, see [here](http://tug.org/pipermail/xetex/2008-February/008706.html).

Comment: @Alexey: So you are replying in 2017 to an answer from 2013 with a mailing list post from 2008 answering a totally unrelated question?

Comment: How is the question unrelated? "Latin Modern" does not quite work by default in XeLaTeX. It has to be loaded with `\setmainfont`, otherwise some features, like `\oldstylenums`, do not work.

Comment: @Alexey where do you see any mention of `\oldstylenums` in the question above!

Comment: I do not see `\oldstylenums` in the question above, i am saying that Latin Modern does not quite work by default, and some actions are needed to use it fully.